# How to use concat and group by in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, group-by

I want to get data using `GROUP BY` and `CONCAT`. I can get this data in SQL Inline editor I want to know that how I can get this in Laravel.
I want my desired result like in attached images

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT created_at, GROUP_CONCAT(answer) FROM answers
where cid=293 and qid in (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
group by created_at
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using Eloquent or Query Builder?

Comment: @Daniel Eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent query should looks like this:

```php
$answers = Answer::select('created_at')
              ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(answer)')
              ->where('cid', 293)
              ->whereIn('qid', [7,8,9,10,11,12])
              ->groupBy('created_at')
              ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this ,

```
$list = Modelname::where('cid', 293)
        ->whereIn('qid',[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12])
        ->select('created_at')
        ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(answer) as answer')
        ->groupBy('created_at')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Thanku very much.. you save  my day